# Why is Coq prepending "Top." to my terms?

Tags: coq

Why am I getting the following error message:

```
The term "H1" has type
 "C Top.d2 w21"
while it is expected to have type
 "C d2 w21".
```

"d2" is defined as follows in my code:

```
Inductive D : Type := 
  | d1 : D
  | d2 : D
  | d3 : D
.
```

The full error message is the following:

```
Error:
In environment
w, w1, w2, w3 : W
H : hide s0 =
    (w1 :: w2 :: w3 :: nil)%list
H1C : C d1 w1
H2C : C Top.d2 w2
H3C : C Top.d3 w3
w11 : W
H11 : pick d1 w1 =
      (w11 :: nil)%list
H11P : P d1 w11
w21 : W
H21 : pick d1 w2 =
      (w21 :: nil)%list
H21P : P d1 w21
w31 : W
H31 : pick d1 w3 =
      (w31 :: nil)%list
H31P : P d1 w31
H0 : C d1 w11
H1 : C Top.d2 w21
H2 : C Top.d3 w31
w112, w113 : W
d2, d3 : D
H11Open : open w11 =
          (w112 :: w113 :: nil)%list
D21 : d2 <> d1
D31 : d3 <> d1
D23 : d2 <> d3
H112O : O d2 w112
H113O : O d3 w113
The term "H1" has type
 "C Top.d2 w21"
while it is expected to have type
 "C d2 w21".
```

I don't understand why only "d2" and "d3" receive the "Top." prefix and cause problems. I did nothing different for "d2" and "d3" that I ahven't done for d1.

Why is Coq wrongly adding this prefix?

**Edit:**

Here is my proof script:

```
Lemma changeprob: [ (At s0 (probPred Vic (cons hide (cons (pick d1) (cons open (cons (pick d2) nil) ) ) ) (2 # 3))) ].
Proof. mv.
unfold At.
unfold probPred.
unfold prob.
destruct (hide2 s0) as [w1 [w2 [w3 H ]]].  (* H : hide s0 =
(w1 :: w2 :: w3 :: nil)%list /\
C d1 w1 /\ C d2 w2 /\ C d3 w3 *)
destruct H as [H [H1C [H2C H3C]]].
rewrite H. simpl.
destruct (pick2 w1 d1) as [w11 [H11 H11P]].
destruct (pick2 w2 d1) as [w21 [H21 H21P]].
destruct (pick2 w3 d1) as [w31 [H31 H31P]].
rewrite H11; rewrite H21; rewrite H31; simpl.
assert (C d1 w11). (* H0 *)
  apply (frame w1 d1 d1 H1C); unfold r; unfold is_in; rewrite H11; left; reflexivity.

  assert (C d2 w21). (* H1 *)
    apply (frame w2 d2 d1 H2C); unfold r; unfold is_in; rewrite H21; left; reflexivity.

    assert (C d3 w31). (* H2 *)
      apply (frame w3 d3 d1 H3C); unfold r; unfold is_in; rewrite H31; left; reflexivity.


  destruct (open1 w11 d1 H0 H11P) as [w112 [w113 [d2 [d3 [H11Open [D21 [D31 [D23 [H112O H113O]]]]] ]]]].
  destruct (open2 w21 d2 d1 H1 H21P) as [w213 HNN]. (* This line throws the error *)
```

"frame", "hide2", "pick2", "open1" and "open2" are axioms (shown below).

Note that H0, H1 and H2 were created in exactly the same way, through "assert". Likewise, H1C, H2C and H3C were created in exactly the same way, through "destruct". But, for some reason, Coq adds the "Top." prefix before d2 and d3, but not before d1. The "Top." appears only in error messages. It does not appear in the output shown in the upper-right panel of the CoqIDE.

Note also that the second last "destruct" tactic in the proof script above works perfectly fine, because Coq did not add the "Top." prefix to d1 in H0. On the other hand, the last "destruct" tactic triggers the error, because Coq added the "Top." prefix to d2 in H1.

So, why is Coq adding the "Top." prefix? And why is it doing that only to some of my terms, even though I am creating the terms in the same way? What is the "Top." prefix? How can I prevent Coq from adding it?

**Appendix:**

"frame", "hide2", "pick2", "open1" and "open2" are axioms:

```
Axiom hide2: forall w, exists w1 w2 w3, (hide w) = (cons w1 (cons w2 (cons w3 nil))) /\ (C d1 w1) /\ (C d2 w2) /\ (C d3 w3). 

Axiom pick2: forall w, forall d, exists w1, (pick d w) = (cons w1 nil) /\ (P d w1).

Axiom frame: [mforall d, mforall dp, (C d) m-> (box (pick dp) (C d)) ].

Axiom open1: forall w, forall d, ((C d) w) -> ((P d) w) -> exists w1 w2 d1 d2, (open w) = (cons w1 (cons w2 nil)) /\ ~(d1 = d) /\ ~(d2 = d) /\ ~(d1 = d2) /\ (O d1 w1) /\ (O d2 w2).

Axiom open2: forall w, forall d, forall dd, ((C d) w) -> ((P dd) w) -> exists w1, (open w) = (cons w1 nil) /\ exists do, ~(do = d) /\ ~(do = dd) /\ (O do w1).
```

Comment: Can you post a complete and reproducable example, including the proof you're working on? [mcve]

Comment: I tried to produce a minimal example exhibiting the same behaviour, but I failed. My real problem is quite non-minimal. I will add part of my proof script to my question. I hope this will help a bit.

Comment: You could use the collacoq service to post a complete working example, I'm much afraid that without being able to run the code we cannot really help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually due to a namespace overlap. It is difficult to guess without a complete example, this code illustrates the problem:

```
Module A.

  Definition u := 3.
  Lemma v : u = u.
  Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

End A.

Import A.
Definition u := 4.
Print v.
```

Comment: I have the following in my code:

     Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith.
     Open Scope Q_scope.

Comment: Can it be that the QArithm module introduces "d2" and "d3", and Coq decides to prefix my definitions of "d2" and "d3" with "Top." ?

Comment: Yes, this is due to namespace management. I don't have a Coq instance to find which part is defining `d2` and `d3` but there is a conflict somewhere, so Coq prepend `Top.` to distinguish from current module and imported modules

Comment: @Ceilican, you can use `About d2` and `About Top.d2` to see where the symbols are defined.

Comment: @ejgallego , thank you! I did not know about "About".  ```About d2.``` gave me "Hypothesis of the goal context.", whereas ```About Top.d2.``` gave me "Expands to: Constructor Top.d2".  Then it became clear to me that my second last "destruct" was creating another d2 in the hypothesis, which was forcing Coq to expand the existing d2 to Top.d2.  I would have preferred that Coq warned me about the name clash.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Ceilican having a sensible policy for name clashes may be hard in general. However, Coq internally has extensive support for namespace management, so it should be doable. Maybe you could file a bug in the coq's bugtracker? (Disclaimer, I didn't check if there is an existing bug report for that).

Comment: @ejgallego , good suggestion. I have just done it: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4645